# How should I generate Kochanek-Bartels spline endpoints?

Tags: curve

I'm working on a program which uses Kochanek-Bartels ("TCB") splines.

My question is: How do I deal with the first/last points of the spline?

This type of spline needs a 'previous' and 'next' point at each node to generate the curve tangents, but the first and last points on the curve don't have them. How do graphics programs deal with this problem?